# Implementing a neuralnetwork from scratch in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm working on an assignment for my Machine Learning course, and as part of it I'm trying to implement a neural network. Since it's for school, I have to implement the algorithm manually, and not use any of the neuralnet packages available.

I've been using the material in "Learning from Data" along with the CalTech lectures that follow it on youtube.

I've put together the algorithm in R to the best of my ability, but there's something going wrong along the way. I haven't been able to implement the difference in the cost function as a measure for when the last iteration should be, so for now I've just fixed the number of iterations as a constant.

** Edit **
Hey guys. Thanks for the response. I can see I'm missing a lot of needed information. Sorry about that, don't really know what I was thinking.

The data I'm using is simply "toy data" generated from the sinc function sinc(x)=sin(x)/x.

The problem I'm having specifically is that the estimates that I get at the end of the algorithm are completely off from the real values, and they are significantly different every time I run the algorithm. It seems like I've put the algorithm together the way the book states, but I can't see where the problem is.

***Edit 2***
Added the data to the code so it can be run without doing anything extra. I also separated the individual parts of the function. As i mentioned in a comment, I was able to numerically verify the partial derivatives, so I think that part is ok. The problem I have is when I need to update the weights in order to train the network.
It's not in this part of the code, but I thought that in order to update the weights, you simply took the old weight and subtracted the partial derivative of that weight scaled by the learning rate? (wNew = wOld - eta*djdwOld)

```
theta <- function(a){
  a / (1+abs(a))      # Here we apply the sigmoid function as our
  # non-linearity.
}
theta.prime <- function(a){
  1 / (1+abs(a))^2
}

x <- c( 5.949110, -1.036600,  3.256780,  7.824520, -3.606010,  3.115640, -7.786960,
        -7.598090,  2.083880,  3.983000,  8.060120,  7.879760, -2.456670,
         -2.152720,  3.471950,  3.567960, -4.232630,  6.831610, -9.486860,  8.692330,
        -1.551860,  0.917305,  4.669480, -7.760430,  2.835410)
y <- c(-0.10804400,  0.78264000, -0.05313330,  0.13484700, -0.05522470, -0.05758530,
         0.19566100,  0.13846000,  0.43534100, -0.16861400,  0.10625000,
          0.08427310,  0.27012900,  0.44004800, -0.00880575, -0.10711400, -0.18671100,
         0.01158470,  0.02767190,  0.06319830,  0.61802000,  0.87124300,
         -0.25668100,  0.06160800, 0.10575700)

inputlayer <- 1
outputlayer <- 1
hiddenlayer <- 2

w1 <- t(matrix(rnorm(hiddenlayer,0,.01),hiddenlayer,inputlayer)) 
w2 <- matrix(rnorm(hiddenlayer,0,.01),hiddenlayer,outputlayer)


### Forwardprop ###
forward <- function(x,w1,w2,theta){
s2 <- x%*%w1
a2 <- apply(s2,c(1,2),theta)
s3 <- a2%*%w2
yhat <- apply(s3,c(1,2),theta)
return(yhat)
}

### Forwardpropagation maunally ###
s2 <- x%*%w1
a2 <- apply(s2,c(1,2),theta)
s3 <- a2%*%w2
yhat <- apply(s3,c(1,2),theta)
### Error function ###
#yhat <- forward(x,w1,w2,theta)
E <- sum((y-yhat)^2)/(length(x))

### Backward Propagation ###
delta3 <- (-2*(y-yhat)) * apply(s3,c(1,2),theta.prime)
djdw2 <- t(a2) %*% delta3
delta2 <- delta3 %*% t(w2) * apply(s2,c(1,2),theta.prime)
djdw1 <- t(x)%*%delta2


### Numerically estimated gradients ###
e <- 1e-8
numgrad1 <- matrix(0,1,2)
eps <- matrix(0,1,2)
w1e <- matrix(0,1,2)

for(j in 1:2) {
  eps[1,j] <- e
  w1e <- w1 + eps
  loss2 <- sum((y-forward(x,w1e,w2,theta))^2)

  w1e <- w1
  loss1 <- sum((y-forward(x,w1e,w2,theta))^2)

  numgrad1[1,j] <- (loss2 - loss1)/(e)
  eps[1,j] <- 0
}


numgrad2 <- matrix(0,2,1)
eps <- matrix(0,2,1)
w2e <- matrix(0,2,1)

for(j in 1:2) {
  eps[j,1] <- e
  w2e <- w2 + eps
  loss2 <- sum((y-forward(x,w1,w2e,theta))^2)

  w2e <- w2
  loss1 <- sum((y-forward(x,w1,w2e,theta))^2)

  numgrad2[j,1] <- (loss2 - loss1)/(e)
  eps[j,1] <- 0
}

# Comparison of our gradients from backpropagation
# and numerical estimation.
c(djdw1,djdw2)
c(numgrad1,numgrad2)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
In particular, "there's something going wrong" is not a problem specification.  "I hope you can make out what I'm doing" shows that you *know* this isn't yet ready for others to digest.  However, you *have* used variables clearly drawn from standard algorithm notation, so that part isn't fatal.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ is a big help; we should also have the benefit of your detailed efforts to debug the program, rather than having to reproduce effort you've already taken.

Comment: This is somewhat improved with edits, but still doesn't **demonstrate** a problem."*"toy data" generated from the sinc function sinc(x)=sin(x)/x*" hints that your data generation is univariate (?) and with no added random noise (?)... what would make it clear is explicit code to generate the toy data, with `set.seed` if there is a random element, and then showing how you call your function. (Are you passing something to `neurons`? What is it?)

Comment: Also, some debugging on your end would be a good sign of faith, as in Prune's second link. So, the final results are off. Have you been able to check any intermediate results? Can you break the function into smaller pieces and check them individually? Does it work on an even simpler input? What if you input linear data? Constant data?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've checked my code through and through, and I can't seem to find any issues. I've verified my partial derivatives from backpropagation numerically, so I think things are running as they should. The problem is when I try to train the network. I guess my question is how am I supposed to update the weights correctly so my network starts making accurate estimates?